# CSS Border over div columns

Tags: html, css, border

I want to design some speech bubble like comment box in HTML with CSS. However I can't get the filler div to use the remaining width.

[image]

So how can I get the border to be complete?

I created a jsfiddle with my complete code (except for the images). http://jsfiddle.net/qHVk3/

Comment: Unless I'm somehow missing it, you didn't actually post the jsfiddle you mentioned.

Comment: Ah sorry, now its there.

Comment: what is the filler suppose to do? complete the bottom border?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I could drop it if its not needed.

Comment: I think you are taking a very complicated approach for no reason. simply have the #header box, with the green border all around it, then add the tip as a background image on the arrow div and give it a negative margin

Comment: You are right, this would be an easier approach ;). Thx. However the answer from David Nguyen thought me something new, so at least my approach wasn't for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I was able to do, basically filler is 100% wide but is under the arrow.

http://jsfiddle.net/aWxPX/

Comment: Thank you so much. This took me a few hours :). Would have never thought about the z-index. And I never used "clear" before. Thx!

Comment: it's called clear fix and it sets a div height when you have a float in a non float div.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the width of the whole bubble?  You could split up the space between the date div and the filler div then.

Comment: Yes, but this feels like a workaround :). I found some similar solutions for this problem, but all where with hard coded widths.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing a lot more complex css than what you need to.

Take a look at this, it is a speech bubble done completely with css and one paragraph tag:
http://jsfiddle.net/XBZaA/2/

It comes from here and you can get all sorts of complex styles of arrows and thought bubbles depending on the css and how many html elements you're ok with:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

HTML

```
<p class="triangle-border">This only needs one HTML element.</p>
```

CSS

```
.triangle-border {
    position:relative;
    padding:15px;
    margin:1em 0 3em;
    border:5px solid #5a8f00;
    color:#333;
    background:#fff;
    /* css3 */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.triangle-border:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
    border-width:20px 20px 0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#5a8f00 transparent;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block; 
    width:0;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left:47px; /* value = (:before left) + (:before border-left) - (:after border-left) */
    border-width:13px 13px 0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#fff transparent;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block; 
    width:0;
}
```

Comment: This is extremely nice. I didn't know you can do this with pure CSS.